# Secure way to allow any user to run programs in specific network namespace

Tags: networking, sudo, network-namespaces

I have a cell modem connected to my server that I want to use as a means to get notification emails out when the landline dies.

To nicely separate normal network access and this exceptional cell modem access, I created a network namespace and created the network device in there as the only device.  To have a program use the cell modem I simply use `ip netns exec`.

The wrinkle is that I want to allow any user to run any program they wish in the namespace, but `netns exec` requires root.  My solution is as follows:

/usr/local/sbin/_oob_shim:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd_line="$@"
/bin/ip netns exec oob \
    /usr/bin/sudo -u "#$SUDO_UID" -g "#$SUDO_GID" /bin/sh -c "$cmd_line"
```

/etc/sudoers:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/_oob_shim
```

I figure the only way to run the shim without already being root or knowing the root password is through sudo, and I can trust sudo to set $SUDO_UID and $SUDO_GID to the right values.

Am I opening myself up to significant risk?  Or, should I say am I missing any obvious caveats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only bug I see with your code is that you're running the user's command unnecessarily through `sh -c` when you should just run it directly. Running it through `sh -c` buys you nothing but it destroys quoting that the user originally put into the command. For example, try this:

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/_oob_shim ls -l "a b"
```

should list a file called `a b` inside the context of the namespace but instead it lists two files called `a` and `b`.

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/_oob_shim ls -l "*"
```

should list a file called `*` (literal asterisk), fails for the same reason.

So it should look like this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/ip netns exec oob \
    /usr/bin/sudo -u "#$SUDO_UID" -g "#$SUDO_GID" -- "$@"
```

Makes the script simpler to boot!

Another point I can make is that although in this case the bug was just a functionality bug, not a security bug, one is always suspicious when auditing security-sensitive code and finding that it runs things through shells because that's almost always a problem.

Finally, the user's supplementary groups will not be propagated into the namespace (they get only their uid and main gid), but that doesn't seem like a huge problem and fixing that is not trivial.

Other than that, it looks good to me.

Comment: Using the shell didn't quite buy me nothing, it prevents `sudo /usr/local/sbin/_oob_shim -u root cat /etc/shadow` which is a hole in your suggested version.  You're totally right about the quoting though, I'll start with `sudo -u "#$SUDO_UID" -g "#$SUDO_GID" -- "$@"` and keep looking for security holes.

Comment: You're *so* right about the user being able to override options with my version. I totally missed that. Your solution of using `--` if of course correct. I'd better edit that in to my answer!