# What script could allow regular users to use network namespaces?

Tags: sudo, root, privileges, network-namespaces

I have an architecture using network namespaces (netns). I would like to allow regular users to do some operations in these netns.

I could write a script `netns-exec.sh`, inspired by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189865/secure-way-to-allow-any-user-to-run-programs-in-specific-network-namespace), executed with `sudo`, containing:

```
ip netns exec $1 su $USER -c "$2"
```

and add to my sudoer file:

```
user ALL=(ALL) /path/to/netns-exec.sh
```

But I find it so ugly I could totally have nightmares about it.
Is there a better solution to allow regular users to use namespaces? Is it possible to put users to some useful groups? I searched about it but found nothing.

Comment: why dont you define `Cmd_Alias CMD_NETNS = ip netns exec [regexp matching your namespace] su [regexp matching allowed used] -c [regexp matching allowed namespace command]` in your sudoers file and then create a group in which you put your allowed users, and associate this group to this command alias.

Comment: It's the `sudo` containing a `su` that annoys me, not the script itself. Anyway I'll write a script to wrap the thing. It makes 2 user switches, that's really ugly, don't you think ?

Comment: That should scare you. The user could modify $USER to be root.

Comment: Yes, and it does scares me. But I figured out later that `sudo` provided a specific variable `$SUDO_USER`, which is safer. But that's still ugly.

Comment: You could do setuid on the script.

Comment: @Elronnd - kernel ignores setuid on scripts

Answer (score 3):

**[Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail/)**
can do the job

```
firejail --noprofile --netns=nameOfNetSpace command
```

**Alternatively [Netns-Exec](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Namespace/Netns-Exec), [Nsutils](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Namespace/Namespace-Utils) and [Netns](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/netns)** does not require root

Comment: you must have root privileges to use "ip netns"

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Just add a group called "netns" add all the wanted users to it.
Then give ownership to root:netns and give read/exec capabilities to the group.

In other terms :

```
# New group netns
sudo groupadd --system netns

# Add root to "netns", not sure if needed
sudo usermod -aG netns root

# Do this for every needed user
sudo usermod -aG netns $UserName

# Change ownership to root, grant rw acces to group netns
sudo chown root:netns /path/to/netns-exec.sh
sudo chmod 633 /path/to/netns-exec.sh
```

---

**Solution 2**

This solution is simpler, you have to edit you sudoers file as shown in [this example](http://www.atrixnet.com/allow-an-unprivileged-user-to-run-a-certain-command-with-sudo/).

```
user ALL=(ALL) /bin/ip netns
```

Comment: Well, solution 1 is impossible, the command `ip netns` will return an error saying that only root can execute it. Solution 2 is what I had initially in mind, but wasn't satisfying in my opinion.

Comment: This `chmod 0633` would give `write+execute` permissions to all users and to the `netns` group. I suspect you wanted to set the SGID bit on the script, but as @Angelo mentioned: `setuid` and `setgid` is ignored for shell scripts, and [for good reason](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html "Section - How can I get setuid shell scripts to work?").

Answer (score 1):

Not a script, but I wrote an ultra-minimalist and hopefully-paranoid-enough C program that allows a non-root user to execute a process inside a Linux network namespace.

The source code is here: [netns-exec.c](https://gist.github.com/parke/6c2918a4dea329ae9e7ac238b6ee70bf)

Answer (score -2):

Personally I do not know if there is possibility to permit regular users to run commands in different network namespaces, but this annotated shell script may better suit your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ip netns wrapper script, nns.
# Usage: nns nsname cmdline

case "${1}" in
    do)
        shift # remove "do"
        NSNAME="${1}" # remember nsname
        shift # remove nsname to get argument list for su -c
        [ -z "${NSNAME}" -o -z "${1}" ] && exit 1 # if either nsname or arglist is empty - error out
        echo ip netns exec "${NSNAME}" su "${SUDO_USER}" -c "${*}" # execute, ${*} merges separate arguments into single word for su/sh -c parsing. See with strace.
    ;;
    *)
        SCRIPTNAME="${0}" # remember script full path
        exec sudo "${SCRIPTNAME}" do "${@}" # run it through sudo with elevated privileges
    ;;
esac
```

Install it somewhere in `/usr/bin` and allow your users to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for your response (and sorry for noticing several months after). But the problem remains the same, that is to say using sudo.