# How can I constrain a user application to always run in a particular network namespace?

Tags: network-namespaces

I need to be able to constrain a user application to always run in a particular network namespace. Assume I have previously set up my network configuration as such:

```
ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip netns add appns

ip link set dev tap0 netns appns
ip link set dev veth0 netns appns
ip netns exec appns ip addr add 10.0.0.254/24 dev tap0
ip netns exec appns ip link set dev tap0 up
ip netns exec appns ip addr add 10.20.30.1/24 dev veth0
ip netns exec appns iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o veth0 -j SNAT --to 10.20.30.1

ip link add name br1 type bridge
# eth1 previously exists, maps to physical interface
ip link set dev eth1 master br1
ip link set dev veth1 master br1
ip link set dev eth1 up
ip link set dev br1 up
```

With this setup, I would like to have any non-sudo users¹ be able to run `myapp` such that `myapp` will be executing within the `appns` namespace, as if the user had run

```
> sudo ip netns exec appns sudo -u ${USER} myapp
```

`myapp` will read/write from the `tap0` interface at `10.0.0.x`, communicating with something at `10.20.30.x`.

I can't create a shell wrapper with `setuid` set (per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/37941) to allowing setuid on shell scripts). How would I go about always having `myapp` always run in the `appns` network namespace? Could I make the namespace name configurable via some .conf file?

¹ These users can be part of a group that is necessary to run the application (e.g., similar to being in the `wireshark` group to run Wireshark).

Comment: As far as I can work it out, you'll need to write your own program to call `setns` and `execv` or similar, and make that be suid root. Though I haven't worked with namespaces much, and there may well be some ready-made utility that I don't know of.

Comment: This [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189865/119298) used a secure shell script solution.